# Compensa armazenar o valor de um membro de struct em variável local?

Tags: c, c++, variáveis, desempenho, struct

Eu vejo vários programadores fazendo isto. No lugar de acessar o membro de uma `struct` diretamente, ele copia o valor para uma variável local à função e usa esta variável.

Há ganho de performance nisso? Faz diferença se a estrutura está no *stack* ou *heap*?

Se não há, por que fazer isto?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos criar um código que faça das duas formas de uso da variável, tanto na *stack* como no *heap*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int i;
} Tipo;

int main() {
    Tipo x = { .i = 10 };
    printf("%d", x.i);
    int y = x.i;
    printf("%d", y);
    Tipo *z = malloc(sizeof(Tipo));
    z->i = 10;
    printf("%d", z->i);
    y = z->i;
    printf("%d", y);
}
```

Veja [o Assembly gerado no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/g/zKt83K). Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0jBdra). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/kroifhln-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/LocalVariableXMember.c).

Acessar o membro na *stack* gerou este Assembly:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
mov    esi,eax
mov    edi,0x400694
mov    eax,0x0
call   400460 <printf@plt>
```

E o acesso à variável gerou este Assembly:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
mov    esi,eax
mov    edi,0x400694
mov    eax,0x0
call   400460 <printf@plt>
```

Obviamente o endereço é diferente, mas o código é exatamente o mesmo. Mas para fazer esse segundo teve que haver a cópia do valor da estrutura para a variável local, então teve que executar mais código:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x20]
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

Então o desempenho de usar variável local é pior. Se acessar a variável local várias vezes esse custo adicional acaba sendo diluído, mas ainda será sempre pior. Há códigos que isso não importa. Mas em C tem casos que isso faz diferença. O acesso extra à variável pode custar desde algo em torno de 1 nanossegundo, até há dezenas de nanossegundos, dependendo se está no cache L1 ou precisa acessar a RAM.

Agora vejamos no *heap*, acessando direto:

```
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
mov    esi,eax
mov    edi,0x400694
mov    eax,0x0
call   400460 <printf@plt>
```

E acessando pela variável local:

```
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4]
mov    esi,eax
mov    edi,0x400694
mov    eax,0x0
call   400460 <printf@plt>
```

Aqui o acesso ao membro da estrutura é ligeiramente pior com uma instrução a mais. Se for usar a variável poucas vezes não compensa porque ainda existe um código para fazer a cópia para a variável local, e neste caso é até um pouco mais caro por causa da [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101):

```
mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10]
mov    eax,DWORD PTR [rax]
mov    DWORD PTR [rbp-0x4],eax
```

Se for usar a variável local várias vezes pode compensar sim. A indireção adiciona um custo extra e a variável local pode fazer ele ocorrer apenas uma vez no código.

Se o ganho não ocorre em uma situação específica eu diria que a pessoa copia para a variável local, ou porque quis documentar melhor o que está fazendo usando um nome de variável significativo dando mais legibilidade ao código e a performance não é importante, ou a pessoa não sabe que é potencialmente pior.

Tem linguagem que pode se comportar diferente.

Comment: VocÊ ganha em legibilidade do código - o computador tem capacidade infinita para.ler.nomes.assim  - mas se vocês  só precisa ler os valores do último atributo, só  `assim` é um nome que encurta não so a digitaçõa, mas a leitura do código.

O tempo para copiar o atributo é negligível. 

Agora, em Python por exemplo, sim, o aceso a uma variável local `assim` é mais rápido do que `self.assim` - por que o mecanismo de acesso a atributos é configurável com vários hooks, que são evitados com o assignment.